# Dropbox chunk uploading

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload to dropbox suing chunk uploading in core API. The upload is done in this way:

```
[DropBlocks uploadFileChunk:nil offset:0 fromPath:path){

 NSLog(@"ID: %@, %llu, %@, %@", uploadId, offset, expiresDate, error);
```

from the result everything seems okay, no error.But the files don't show up on dropbox. While if I use the normal uploadFile toPath method it works...

Comment: Show your implementation of the two "uploadFileChunk" related delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with DropBlocks, but in general, after you upload all the chunks of a file, you need to  commit those chunks. That probably means calling [`uploadFile:toPath:withParentRev:fromUploadId:completionBlock:`](https://github.com/natep/DropBlocks/blob/master/DropBlocks/Classes/DropBlocks.h#L62) once the chunks have all been uploaded. Are you doing that?